# C# Where and how to visualize multiple GroupBox'es

Tags: c#, listview, listbox, groupbox

I dynamically generate lots of GroupBoxes(up to 50) and want to visualize(stack) them in a Box with a vertical scrollbar. i tried the `ListBox` and `ListView` without success -> i always got a disabled scrollbar, but couldn't scroll?!

Is the `ListBox` or `ListView` the correct tool?

Comment: what technology you use? Windows 8, WPF, Windows Phone?

Comment: c# express 2010, winxp, win7

Comment: ok but what type of app you creating? WPF, Windows Phone, Windows Forms? What project type You selected on start creating?

Comment: a group box is a kind of container that surrounds controls. did you mean to say checkbox?